# How could I get the needed files from repository if there are a few projects in the repo?

Tags: github

I created a repository with my projects. I lost the project file of one undertaking from the local machine, but the files there are in the remote repo. I can't do a pull or push. I want to pull only the needed project from the repo, not all. The git is writing:

```
$ git push origin main
remote: Not Found
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/daniilalex/daniilalex.github.io/speedrunner/' not found ----------------
$ git pull
remote: Not Found
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/daniilalex/daniilalex.github.io/speedrunner/' not found
```

What should I do to make some changes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository)

Comment: @Schwern, yes, exactly